# Calculate Laurent series for $1/ \sin(z)$

Tags: complex-numbers, laurent-series

How can calculate Laurent series for

$$f(z)=1/ \sin(z) $$ ??

I searched for it and found only the final result, is there a simple way to explain it ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using the series for $\sin(z)$ and [the formula for products of power series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Multiplication_and_division), we can get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\sin(z)}
&=\frac1z\frac{z}{\sin(z)}\\
&=\frac1z\left(1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-\frac{z^6}{7!}+\cdots\right)^{-1}\\
&=\frac1z\left(1+\frac{z^2}{6}+\frac{7z^4}{360}+\frac{31z^6}{15120}+\cdots\right)\\
&=\frac1z+\frac{z}{6}+\frac{7z^3}{360}+\frac{31z^5}{15120}+\cdots
\end{align}
$$

---

**Using the formula for products of power series**

As given in the Wikipedia article linked above,
$$
\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_kz^k\right)
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kz^k\tag{1}
$$
where
$$
c_k=\sum_{j=0}^ka_jb_{k-j}\tag{2}
$$
Set
$$
c_k=\left\{\begin{array}{}
1&\text{for }k=0\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.\tag{3}
$$
and
$$
a_k=\left\{\begin{array}{}
\frac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)!}&\text{for }k=2j\\
0&\text{for }k=2j+1
\end{array}\right.\tag{4}
$$
Using $(2)$, $(3)$, and $(4)$, we can iteratively compute $b_k$.

---

For example, to compute the coefficient of $z^8$:
$$
\begin{align}
c_8=0
&=b_8-\frac16b_6+\frac1{120}b_4-\frac1{5040}b_2+\frac1{362880}b_0\\
&=b_8-\frac16\frac{31}{15120}+\frac1{120}\frac7{360}-\frac1{5040}\frac16+\frac1{362880}1\\
&=b_8-\frac{127}{604800}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $b_8=\dfrac{127}{604800}$.

Comment: Can you please explain the 2nd equation transition ? how did you get rid of the pow(-1) ?

Comment: @FoadRezek: I have added a section on using the formula for products of power series.

Comment: For future reference, to get rid of pow(-1), he treated the part O(z^2) as x and used $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+...$. He then picked out the terms with z^2, z^4 etc. with the method in the link "product of power series".

Comment: @XYSquared: Actually, that is not what I did. This is why I mentioned $(1)$, because I use $(2)$, $(3)$, and $(4)$ to recursively compute the series for $\frac{x}{\sin(x)}$.

Comment: For $k=0$, we get $\overbrace1^{c_0}=\overbrace1^{a_0}b_0$, which gives $b_0=1$. For $k>0$, $$0=b_k+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{(-1)^{(k-j)/2}}{(k-j+1)!}b_j[k-j\text{ is even}]$$ and, if we notice that $b_k=0$ for all odd $k$, this can be rewritten as $$\begin{align} b_{2k}&=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{(-1)^{k-j+1}}{(2k-2j+1)!}b_{2j}\\ b_{2k+1}&=0\end{align}$$

Comment: Sorry! I didn't understand your answer fully before posting that. I think I get it now: $a_k$ are $1, 0, \frac{-1}{3!}, 0, \frac{1}{5!}, \dots$ while $b_k$ are the coefficients we want to solve and $c_k$ are just the coefficients to the "fake series" $1 + 0z^1 + 0z^2 + 0z^3 + \dots$. Never thought of this smart way to get the inverse!

Comment: Just curious: is there a closed-form solution to the recursive definition of coefficients $b_{2k}?

Comment: May I also ask which college/graduate courses deal with these series calculations? Are they courses about combinatorics?

Comment: There is no closed form for $b_{2k}$, unless you use Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: What courses cover these calculations may vary. Some might be covered in a course on Discrete Math; some might be covered in an advanced course on series or special functions. It is being covered some here, and in other answers to questions tagged [tag:sequences-and-series].

Answer (score 6):

From the [generating function of the Bernoulli polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials):
$${\frac {t{{\rm e}^{xt}}}{{{\rm e}^{t}}-1}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{
\frac {{\it B}_{n}\left(x\right) {t}^{n}}{n!}} \tag{1}$$
and from:
$$ \frac{1}{\sin(z)}={\frac {-2i{{\rm e}^{-iz
}}}{{{\rm e}^{-2iz}}-1}} \tag{2}$$
we set $$t=-2iz,\quad x=\frac{1}{2} \tag{3}$$
in $(1)$ to get:
$${\frac {-2iz{{\rm e}^{-iz}}}{{{\rm e}^{-2iz}}-1}}=\sum _{n=0}^{
\infty }{\frac {{\it B_n} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)  \left( -2\,iz
 \right) ^{n}}{n!}} \tag{4}$$
and we then use the known value that relates the polynomial evaluated at $\frac{1}{2}$, to the Bernoulli number:
$${\it B_n} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) = \left( {2}^{1-n}-1 \right) {
\it B_n} \tag{5}$$ 
together with the fact that:
$${\it B}_{2n-1} =
\cases{1/2&$n=1$\cr 0&otherwise\cr} \tag{6}$$
and divide both sides of $(4)$ by $z$ to get:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sin(z)}&=\sum _{n=0}^{
\infty }{2{\it B}_{2n}\frac { (-1)^n\left( 1-2^{2n-1} \right)   z^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}}\\
&=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{6}\,z+{\frac {7
}{360}}\,{z}^{3}+{\frac {31}{15120}}\,{z}^{5}+...
 \tag{7}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Sorry I did not see that Martin had already linked to this type of solution...

Comment: A similar and independent answer is at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4427590/945479

Comment: See also Section 5 in the paper "Xue-Yan Chen, Lan Wu, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, Two identities and closed-form formulas for the Bernoulli numbers in terms of central factorial numbers of the second kind, Demonstratio Mathematica 55 (2022), no. 1, 822--830; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/dema-2022-0166"

Answer (score 3):

Idea: $1=\sin z {1\over\sin z} =$ (known Taylor series)(unknown Laurent series).

EDIT: Solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263522/power-series-with-bernoulli-numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this kind of expansion [Laurent series 1/sin(z)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Laurent%20series%201%2Fsin%28z%29)?
For $z\ne k\pi\:(k\in\mathbb Z)$, the expansion takes
\begin{align}
\frac1{\sin(z)}&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{z(-1)^k}{z^2-k^2\pi^2}.
\end{align}
Its proof can be found here [Lobachevsky Integral Formula](https://hal.science/hal-01539895v3/file/lobachevesky-jolany-hassan.pdf).