# L'Hôpital's Rule for$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}\left( \frac 1 {x^2}-\frac 1 {\tan x } \right )$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm struggling with the following problem: 
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}\left( \frac 1 {x^2}-\frac 1 {\tan x } \right )$$

Below is my work.  But I'm stuck because my denominator equals 0.  What did I do wrong?  Also, a step through of this problem would be great.

[image]

Comment: It's ok. It means your limit equals $\infty$.

Comment: oh really?  so the answer of -1 / 0 is acceptable?  the solution just goes to infinity ?

Comment: $\infty$ is a perfectly valid answer. You may verify this by plotting the graph in Desmos.

Comment: This is also evident from the [Laurent series of $\cot(z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952632/), indeed, around $0$, $\cot(z)$ behaves like $\frac1z$

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a different approach using

- $\frac{\tan x}{x}\stackrel{x \to 0}{\longrightarrow}1$

$$\left( \frac 1 {x^2}-\frac 1 {\tan x } \right ) = \frac 1{x^2}\underbrace{\left( 1-\underbrace{x\frac x {\tan x }}_{\stackrel{x \to 0}{\longrightarrow}0\cdot 1=0} \right )}_{\stackrel{x \to 0}{\longrightarrow}1}\stackrel{x \to 0}{\longrightarrow}+\infty$$

Comment: Simplest approach. +1

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters mention, $\lim_{x\to 0+} \big( \frac1{x^2}-\frac1{\tan x} \big)=+\infty$.

l'Hôpital's rule says that (under suitable conditions) $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$. In other words, it transforms one problem into another problem; if we can solve the new problem, then the old problem has the same solution.

If we encountered the problem $\lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{\sec^2 x-2x}{x^2\sec^2 x+2x\tan x}$ in the wild, we would see that the numerator tends to $1$ while the denominator tends to $0$ through positive values, and hence the limit is $+\infty$. And we wouldn't worry that the denominator tended to $0$ because we know limits act that way sometimes.

So the same is true if we encounter this problem after an application of l'Hôpital's rule. It's a feature, not a bug!

Answer (score 1):

It would be very easy to avoid the L'Hospital Rule. Anyway if you want to use it, you can observe that
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}
{{x^2 }} - \frac{1}
{{\tan x}} = \frac{{\tan x - x^2 }}
{{x^2 \tan x}} \sim \frac{{\tan x - x^2 }}
{{x^3 }} = \frac{{F(x)}}
{{G(x)}},\,\,\,\,\left( {x \to 0} \right)
$$
Now
$$
\frac{{F'(x)}}
{{G'(x)}} = \frac{{1 + \tan ^2 x - 2x}}
{{3x^2 }}
$$
and since
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{1 + \tan ^2 x - 2x}}
{{3x^2 }} =  + \infty 
$$
ad all the hypothesis for de L'Hospital Rule are satisfied, you have that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\tan x - x^2 }}
{{x^3 }} =  + \infty 
$$
so
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) =  + \infty 
$$
in particular your limit is $+\infty$