# Residue of pole of order $3$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, residue-calculus

I was trying to find out the residue of the function:
$$f(z)=\frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{z^2}$$

It is evident that we have $z=0$ as a pole of order $3$.

So we have:
$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z = 0}f(z)=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\left(z^3\times \frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{z^2}\right)$$
So we get:

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}f(z)=\frac{\pi}{2}\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{d}{dz}\left(-\pi z \csc^2 \pi z+\cot(\pi z)\right)$$

But it’s tedious to continue from here. Is there any alternate way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula you’re applying is perhaps best viewed as a bookkeping device to extract the desired coefficient of $z^{-1}$ of the [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) of $f$ at $z=0$. In the present case, it seems easier to work directly with the series. From 
[Laurent series for $\cot (z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952632), we have

$$
\cot z=\frac1z-\frac z3+O\left(z^3\right)\;,
$$

so

$$
\frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{z^2}=\frac1{z^3}-\frac{\pi^2}3\cdot\frac1z+O(z)\;,
$$

from which you can read off that the residue at $z=0$ is $-\frac{\pi^2}3$.

Answer (score 0):

$$Res(f,0)=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\left(z^3\times \frac{\pi\:\cot(\pi z)}{z^2}\right)$$

$=lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}(πz\times \frac{\pi cos(π z)}{sin(πz)})$

$= -π^2/2$ as $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{sin(πz)}{πz}=1$