# Expand $\cot z$ around $z_{0} = n\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, monodromy

I'm trying to expand the function in a Laurent series

$$f(z) = \cot z$$

around the singularity $$z_{0} = n\pi$$
Initially I tried expanding $\tan z$ with a Taylor expansion:

$$\tan(z) = \tan(n\pi) + \tan'(n\pi) (z - n\pi) + \dfrac{tg''(n\pi)}{2}(z - n\pi)^{2} + \dfrac{tg'''(n\pi)}{6}(z - n\pi)^{3} + ...$$

$$\tan(z) = \dfrac{(z - n\pi)}{\cos(n\pi)} + \dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{(z - n\pi)^{3}}{\cos^{4}(n\pi)} + ...$$

To obtain the inverse:

$$\cot z = \dfrac{1}{\tan z} = \left[\dfrac{(z - n\pi)}{\cos(n\pi)}\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{(z - n\pi)}{\cos^{3}(n\pi)}\right)\right]^{-1}$$

But I can't work from here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laurent series for $\cot (z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952632/laurent-series-for-cot-z)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

You were very correct o start with the expansion of the tangent around $n\pi$.

Truncated to some order
$$\tan(z)=(z-\pi  n)+\frac{1}{3} (z-\pi  n)^3+\frac{2}{15} (z-\pi  n)^5+\frac{17}{315} (z-\pi n )^7+O\left((z-\pi  n)^{9}\right)$$

Now, using
$$\cot(z)=\frac 1 {\tan(z)}$$ just perform the long division