# Why does $\frac{\pi \cot(\pi z)}{z^2}$ have a pole at $z=0$ of order $3$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Wolfram Alpha gives me a pole at $z=0$ of order $3$. Why is this the case? The denominator is a polynomial of order $2$?

Comment: The numerator has also a pole at the origin ...

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4541655/finding-poles-or-removable-singularities-of-fz-z-cotz/) MSE question may help you.

Comment: $\frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{z^2} = \frac{\pi \cos(\pi z)}{z^2\sin(\pi z)}$. Now you can see it clearly.

Comment: Hint: are you aware $\lim_{z\to0}\pi z\cot\pi z=1$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Find the least $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $z^nf(z)$ is finite as $z\rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 0):

It is $\cot(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{2n+1}}{\pi^{2n}}\cdot \lambda(2n)\cdot x^{2n-1}$. So use $x = \pi z$ and we have
$$
\frac{\pi\cdot\cot(\pi z)}{z^2} 
=
\pi \cdot \frac{1}{z^2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} 
\frac{2^{2n+1}}{\pi^{2n}}\lambda(2n)\pi^{2n-1}z^{2n-1}
$$
and shortening leads to
$$
\frac{\pi\cdot\cot(\pi z)}{z^2} 
=
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{2n+1}\lambda(2n)z^{2n-3}
=
\frac{1}{z^3}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{2n+1}\lambda(2n)z^{2n}
$$
So for $k\in\{1,2\}$ the series $z^k\cdot \frac{\pi\cdot\cot(\pi z)}{z^2} $ is not defined for $z=0$. But $k=3$ does the trick.