# Cauchy product for the reciprocal of the polynomial $x - 2x^2 + 3x^3 - 4x^4$

Tags: polynomials, power-series, cauchy-product

I have come across some Laurent series in which the denominator of a fraction contains a power series. Looking around I came across this [Calculate Laurent series for $1/ \sin(z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648923/calculate-laurent-series-for-1-sinz) which suggests that it is possible to calculate the reciprocal of a series up to a certain number of term. I have looked at the formula and because of the abstract notation, it is not clear to me how this formula is applied. So for example if I wanted to find the reciprocal of the following polynomial:
$$x - 2x^2 + 3x^3 - 4x^4$$
How would I compute this?

Comment: Have you tried long division?

Comment: Is the Cauchy product formula simply long division?

Comment: I would say yes, essentially.  If we write$$1=(x-2x^2+3x^2-4x^4)({1\over x}+a_0+a_1x+\dots)$$ then the calculations to get the $a_k$ are the same ones we'd make doing a long division, or so it seems to me.

Comment: So from there I just equate the coefficients right? Like equating powers of $x^1$ I would get $a_0 - 2 = 0 ==> a_0 = 2$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: How did you know that reciprocal would start with $x^{-1}$?

Comment: To do long division in this context is simplicity itself. You have to write divisor and dividend in increasing degree, as you have already done with your polynomial $f(x)$. Write the algorithm down and you see immediately that the first monomial in the series for $1/f$ is certainly $x^{-1}$.

Comment: Alternatively, $${1\over x-2x^2+3x^3-4x^4}={1\over x}{1\over 1-2x+3x^2-4x^3}$$ and the second factor is analytic at $x=0$ with value $1$.

Comment: Looking around I have found this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53384/power-series-of-the-reciprocal-does-a-recursive-formula-exist-for-the-coeffic#. Are those formula based on a derivation using long division?