# Laurent series of the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2(e^{z}-e^{-z})}$

Tags: laurent-series

Find the first three nonzero terms of the Laurent series of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2(e^{z}-e^{-z})}$ in the annulus $0 \leq \lvert z \rvert \leq \pi$.

Now, instead of $f(z)$ I found the Taylor series of its reciprocal. Then I tried to multiply it by the Laurent series of $f(z)$ and put it equal to one and then comparing the coefficients. My problem is that since zero is the essential singularity of $f(z)$, we would not have first terms in this case. The reason I think zero is the essential singularity is that we cannot remove zero if we multiply $f(z)$ by $z^n$ for some $n$. Maybe my definition of pole is not correct.

Comment: This may help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648923/calculate-laurent-series-for-1-sinz

Comment: Because $\frac{1}{\sin(iz)} = \frac{1}{i\sinh(z)} = \frac{-2i}{e^z-e^{-z}}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to derive three non-zero terms from the expansion of the denominator of $f(z)$ at $z=0$ and then perform a geometric series expansion. Since
\begin{align*}
e^z-e^{-z}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{z^n}{n!}\\
&=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
we obtain from (1)

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{f(z)}&=\frac{1}{z^2\left(e^z-e^{-z}\right)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2z^3\left(1+\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}+\cdots\right)}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2z^3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}+\cdots\right)^n\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2z^3}\left(1-\left(\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}\right)+\left(\frac{z^4}{3!3!}\right)+\cdots\right)\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2z^3}-\frac{1}{12z}+\frac{7z}{720}+\cdots}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
> and the first three non-zero terms are given in (5).

*Comment:*

- In (2) we take the first three non-zero terms and do not consider higher order terms.
- In (3) we make a geometric series expansion.
- In (4) we observe it is sufficient to develop terms up to $n=2$ and we put all terms of $x$ with higher order than $4$ to $\cdots$.
- In (5) we simplify and see the first three non-zero terms.