# Residue of $\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^\frac{2}{z}}{\sin z}$ at $0$

Tags: residue-calculus, laurent-series, bernoulli-numbers

Is there a nice way to find (and represent) the residue of the function $\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^\frac{2}{z}}{\sin z}$ at $0$?

I tried using the product of the associated Laurent series for $\mathrm{e}^\frac{2}{z}$ and $\dfrac{1}{\sin z}$, but the result is a complicated series, since $\dfrac{1}{\sin z}$ is expressed using the Bernoulli numbers (as shown [in this SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/263577/22728)).

Comment: The residue is $\sum\limits_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}2^{2n+1}(2^{2n-1}-1)B_{2n}}{(2n)!^2}=\sum\limits_{n\ge0}\frac{2(2^{2n}-2)\zeta(2n)}{\pi^{2n}(2n)!}$ which has no closed form.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: That is, indeed, the residue I got, too.